# Missing 1 positional error using plotly dash

Tags: anaconda, data-science, typeerror, plotly-dash

[image]

How to solve this error:

> TypeError: run_server() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'?

Comment: please dont post images of code because we cant copy and paste them :) can you please copy and paste it straight into your post please? thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace `app = dash.Dash` with `app = dash.Dash(__name__)`